# Mule ESB How to dump POST payload to a file

Tags: soap, mule, esb

I am getting started with Mule ESB. I am trying to build a SOAP proxy service that receives a SOAP request and redirects it to a SOAP service.

A simple example like this works fine -

```
<flow name="http_redirectFlow1" doc:name="http_redirectFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8092/HelloProxyService" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:8080/soapsvc/hello" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

Now I want to dump the contents of the request to a file. Which is the best way to do it? I tried to use the File connector by inserting this segment between the inbound and outbound endpoints -

```
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:/temp" outputPattern="temp.txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
```

But that doesn't seem  to work. I get an exception that says "Content must be set before entity is written". Not sure what it is, but I may be completely wrong in how I am doing. Please help....

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. I had to translate the DOM to XML using the dom-to-xml transformer. The XML dump is done as follows :-

```
<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer returnClass="java.lang.String"></mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
<file:outbound-endpoint path="c:/temp" outputPattern="Dump_Rcvd.txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
```

Thanks !

Comment: Accept the answer, so that the forums unanswered questions percentage will be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use `<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>` before `file:outbound-endpoint` that will make the payload as a String format and can be written into a file easily

Answer (score 0):

Use File Connector and Transformers involving Bytearray.